# Symmetric function of the roots of a polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

First, I'm a beginner.

I can compute the sum of roots with the follwing:

```
Roots[x^7 + 5 x^6 + x^5 + x + 1 == 0, x]
Plus @@ (x /. {ToRules[%]}) // Simplify
```

Of course I get, except the sign, the coefficient of x^6.

Now, is there a way to compute more elaborate symmetric functions, for example the sum of xi/xj for all i,j ?

Comment: `f[k_] := Root[Function[x, x^7 + 5 x^6 + x^5 + x + 1], k]; Sum[f[i]/f[j], {i, 7}, {j, 7}]` ?

Comment: Also take a look at `Outer`.

Comment: Thanks. In some way, it works, but Mma does not seem to be able to simplify this (well, at least with Simplify). Is there a way to resort directly to polynomial coefficients? I know how to do that by hand, but I wonder if there is an easy way to automate this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "resort directly to polynomial coefficients".  Do you just not want to see `Root` objects?  BTW take a look at `RootSum` too.

Comment: I'm not really interested by root objects, but by the actual result. Any symmetric polynomial (or rational function) of the roots can be computed from the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), hence from the polynomial coefficients. For example, the sum in your first comment has value exactly 5 (you can check with N), but Simplify does not work. So my question is: is there a way to simplify such symmetric rational functions in Mathematica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear if this is what you were asking, but it might help:
from the link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial we extract

```
Product[\[Lambda]+Subscript[x, k],{k,7}]==Sum[\[Lambda]^k ee[7-k,7],{k,0,7}]
```

with

```
 ee[k_,n_]:=SymmetricPolynomial[k, Thread[Subscript[x, Range[n]]]]
```

Now, with your definitions:

```
(x/.{ToRules[Roots[x^7+5 x^6+x^5+x+1==0,x]]})//Simplify ; 
ru = Thread[Thread[Subscript[x, Range[7]]] -> %];
Sum[\[Lambda]^k ee[7 - k, 7], {k, 0, 7}]/. ru // FullSimplify
```

returns (* -1+[Lambda]+[Lambda]^5-5 [Lambda]^6+[Lambda]^7  *)

The mathematics of this are obviously clear to you, maybe you had not yet located the function 'SymmetricPolynomial'?

Comment: I admit I have yet to learn most of Mathematica. Though I have already found many equivalents of what I did with Maxima, it's just the beginning! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might compute the defining polynomial for the root quotients directly. Since you are interested in root quotients x/y, call the result z and we have x-y*z as a new polynomial relation. Now use iterated resultants to eliminate x and y.

```
res = 
 Resultant[Resultant[x^7 + 5 x^6 + x^5 + x + 1, x - y*z, x], 
  y^7 + 5 y^6 + y^5 + y + 1, y]

(* Out[45]= 1 - 5 z + z^2 - 2525 z^5 + 60994 z^6 - 70555 z^7 + 
 12038 z^8 - 261 z^9 + 930 z^10 - 50760 z^11 - 167510 z^12 + 
 224509 z^13 - 5732 z^14 + 7071 z^15 + 36884 z^16 + 26408 z^17 + 
 391806 z^18 - 417131 z^19 - 55251 z^20 - 42118 z^21 + 80948 z^22 - 
 122338 z^23 - 498110 z^24 + 498110 z^25 + 122338 z^26 - 80948 z^27 + 
 42118 z^28 + 55251 z^29 + 417131 z^30 - 391806 z^31 - 26408 z^32 - 
 36884 z^33 - 7071 z^34 + 5732 z^35 - 224509 z^36 + 167510 z^37 + 
 50760 z^38 - 930 z^39 + 261 z^40 - 12038 z^41 + 70555 z^42 - 
 60994 z^43 + 2525 z^44 - z^47 + 5 z^48 - z^49 *)
```